# how to make my code to display in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have write some simple python code in wordpress ,when i publish it ,i can't get proper display ,how to set my wordpress or download some plugins to do so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't execute python which is saved inside wordpress..

Comment: i don't want to execute it ,i just want to display it when i publish it,i use wordpress as my notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a plugin? This is one you might be interested in: [Code Markup](http://thunderguy.com/semicolon/wordpress/code-markup-wordpress-plugin/)

If you're looking for syntax highlighting, go for [Prism](http://prismjs.com/) (by Lea Verou)

Btw: For your posting, `<code>` instead of `<pre>` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the html special characters like `<`, `>`, etc by yourself. Than you can post them.

Using the WYSIWYG-Editor in Wordpress should help.